# Angular 5 Cannot find name ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular, angular5

In Angular 5 project, I want to make a scroll to the top of the page which will be called on page load. Below is my code in update-product.component.ts :

```
export class UpdateProductComponent implements OnInit, ngAfterViewChecked 
{
    productUpdateForm: FormGroup;
    dataInvalid = false;
    formErrors = []; 
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

However, as mentioned below, I received such an error message when I run the command: `ng serve` from terminal.

> ERROR in src/app/update-product/update-product.component.ts(15,56):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ngAfterViewChecked'.

But, also note, sometimes the code runs and scrolls properly. But shows the error when run `ng serve` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifecycle interface is called `AfterViewChecked` and a method which you must implement with `ng` prefix -  `ngAfterViewChecked`.

```
import { OnInit, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core'

export class UpdateProductComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

   ngOnInit() { }

   ngAfterViewChecked() { }

}
```

Comment: Now I see :- ERROR in src/app/update-product/update-product.component.ts(15,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AfterViewChecked'.

Comment: I have imported this. However, seeing this error: ERROR in src/app/update-product/update-product.component.ts(15,14): error TS2420: Class 'UpdateProductComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'AfterViewChecked'.
  Property 'ngAfterViewChecked' is missing in type 'UpdateProductComponent'.

Comment: import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

Answer (score 1):

1]Import AfterViewChecked in angular core

```
import{AfterViewChecked}from '@angular/core';
```

2]Correct below line to AfterViewChecked

```
export class UpdateProductComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked
```